# how to get the result of a mysql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a project using Laravel 10 with mysql and I have these tables:

```
users
=====
id | username | email
---------------------
culinaries
==========
id | title | cover_photo | status | type | user_id
--------------------------------------------------
paradises
=========
id | title | cover_photo | status | type | user_id
--------------------------------------------------
notifications
=============
id | type | post_id | post_type
-------------------------------
 * type: enum('user_created_culinary', 'user_created_paradise', 'admin_approved_culinary', 'admin_rejected_culinary', 'admin_approved_paradise', 'admin_rejected_paradise', 'other_notif_types')
 * post_type : string (only contains either 'culinary' or 'paradise' for now)
 * post_id : unsignedBigInteger as foreign key to either 'culinaries' or 'paradises' tables based on the 'post_type'.
```

I want to read the data from `notifications` table using this code in my API Controller file:

```
        $culinarySubquery = Culinary::select('id', 'title', 'cover_photo', DB::raw('"culinary" as module_name'))
            ->where('status', 'published')
            ->where('type', 'public');

        $paradiseSubquery = Paradise::select('id', 'title', 'cover_photo', DB::raw('"paradise" as module_name'))
            ->where('status', 'published')
            ->where('type', 'public');
        
        $subquery = $culinarySubquery->unionAll($paradiseSubquery);

        $notifications = Notification::select('n.id', 'n.user_id', 'users.username', 'n.post_type', 'n.post_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'n.user_id')
            ->leftJoinSub($subquery, 'tbl', function ($join) {
                $join->on('tbl.id', '=', 'n.post_id')
                    ->whereColumn('tbl.module_name', '=', 'n.post_type');
            })
            ->orderBy('n.user_id')
            ->orderBy('n.id')
            ->get();
        dd($notifications);
```

but I'm getting the error message below when I try to run it on Postman:

```
    "message": "Method Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse::first does not exist.",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
```

what am I doing wrong? what is the solution? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whatever raises the error, isn't included in your code. The message says that you're using the method `first` on the `JsonResponse` and I can't see a reference to either in the code you shared.

Comment: neither do I. I don't remember using any method called `first` anywhere in my project, ever. but no matter, I have found out the problem source and I'm posting the answer now.

Comment: Share the entire controller method.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I missed a simple thing.. I haven't declare the `n` alias that is being used. once I added a `from('notifications as n')`, it works fine.